# selecting on dom parser using jquery with relevant class div12 div31 all at one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for reading my post..

Just consider the below scenario of html architecture.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="doubt-123232" id="value"></div>
    <div class="question></div>
    <div class="doubt-232323" id="query"></div>
</div>
```

In the above DOM if you need to select the class starting with `doubt-*****` (which include `doubt-123232`, `doubt-232323`) all at a time and do processing using jQuery.

We can select each class one by one and do processing, but in my page I have lot like this . I cant do it for each class to select and do processing then it became a trivial process.

Is there way to select the similar class or id all at time for processing in jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for all your reply all works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using [`Attribute Starts With`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) Selector:

```
var divs = $('div[class^="doubt-"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`var items = $('div[class^=doubt]');`

This is known as the "starts with" selector.

Alternatively you could use:

`var items = $('div[class*=doubt]');`

which is the "contains" selector.

Note that in this case, `doubt` is one word.  If there are multiple words with spaces in between, you should put quotes around them.  It is not required to quote single words.

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for documentation on the "starts with" selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
var divs = $('div[class^="doubt-"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

selecting them all:

```
var doubts= $('[class^="doubt-"]');
```

then you access them:

```
doubts.each(function(index){
    this. ... // and so on
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
$("[class^=doubt-]").each(function(){ //do some staff  });
```